# How to set TargetSite.Name of Exception during UT in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing

In our dev code, we need to use TargetSite info to get which method threw exception and custom handle them.
Like

```
var methodErrorOccurred = ex.TargetSite.Name;
        switch (methodErrorOccurred)
        {
            case 1:
              Handle1();
              break;
            case 2:
              Handle2();
              break;
            ...
        }
```

But it seems that the TargetSite is read-only and can be set only during runtime, we cannot mock the real TargetSite during UT, if I use FluentAssertions to

```
Foo(Arg.Is(blabla)).Throws(new Exception());
```

The TargetSite of this exception is not "Foo"
is there any way to achieve it?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the code which you are unit testing along with the test code?

Comment: This is a bit of an educated guess but there is an `Exception` constructor that takes a `SerializationInfo` object as an argument. Can you mock the method being called to throw an exception created in that way with specific information that will generate the `TargetSite` value you want?

Comment: Might depend on the exact .NET version, but using some reflection it would be possible. The [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/exception.cs) for Excception is available. You could either set `_exceptionMethodString` field or serialize the exception, modify ExceptionMethod and deserialize again.

Comment: Thank you all, I attempt to set _exceptionMethodString field, it can work!